# The project type is not supported by this installation... vs2010 mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to open a mvc3 project on my system, but I'm getting an error message in a popup saying 'one or more projects were not loaded correctly .please see the output window for details' and when I close the popup , below I'm seeing a message 'The project type is not supported by this installation.'

I have mvc3 installed on my system and this project is developed in mvc3. I am not sure what is the issue, many times when I try to open projects developed on other machines, I get the same error.  I am able to develop mvc3 projects on my system and run them with out any issues

Comment: There's a big possibility the project is not really built with MVC 3. Perhaps in MVC 4?

Comment: no, i checked it twice, its in mvc3 and its working fine in other systems which have only mvc3

Comment: How sure are you that you have MVC 3 installed? i.e. Do you have the option of creating a new MVC 3 project?

Comment: yes and i created many mvc3 projects using 'asp.net mvc3 web application template'..but i uninstalled mvc2?

Comment: maybe the solution contains some other class library projects that are not compatibles or not being loaded correctly (if you use git, svn or TFS). anyway I've had this problem a few times and it was all about the class library projects came with the solution

Comment: @ePezhman how to resolve this issue?

Comment: usually they VS are backward compatible so there should not be a problem, make sure all projects were copied correctly and their projects files are fine to open.

Answer (score 0):

maybe one or more files isn't available in your project files. check files included your project in explorer